# Does Sitecore support internationalization with Urls?

Tags: multilingual, urls

Clearly, Sitecore has great support for internationalization with built in language versions. However, one thing I have not been a fan of is that fact that all languages will have the same Url (at least that was the case). So the url /store in English might be /es-es/store in Spanish instead of /es-es/tienda.

Has Sitecore introduced or have I been unaware of the ability to provide language specific Url name for the same item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your request you can use Display name functionality

Display names can include characters not allowed in item names.

Display names can vary by language, where item names cannot.

Because display names can vary by language, and item URLs can contain display names rather than item names, URLs for individual items can vary by language (beyond hostname, language path prefix, and/or query string variations that can specify languages)

More information you can find here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-idiosyncrasies-display-name

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090959/sitecore-8-how-to-set-display-name